# Missing bulletpoint / list item in HTML output from rmarkdown

Tags: html, r-markdown, knitr

I have just come across a curious issue.

This:

```
There are two ways to apply the filter:

- [Parallel] run: paralellized execution, which is faster and uses more resources (recommended).
- [Sequential] run: one image is processed at a time, which can be slow on large datasets.

#### Sequential
```

Produces this:

[image: correct]

However, this:

```
There are two ways to apply the filter:

- [Parallel]: paralellized execution, which is faster and uses more resources (recommended).
- [Sequential]: one image is processed at a time, which can be slow on large datasets.

#### Sequential
```

Produces the following output, in which the second bullet-point is missing:

[image: missing]

Does anybody know what is causing it? There are no warnings or messages in the console output.

Here is the [full rmd notebook](https://github.com/darksideoftheshmoo/rcell2-cellid/blob/42979988cdcea180fe1b566b11483c7c015bb475/inst/rmarkdown/templates/rmd_template.cellid/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd#L633).

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your colon with a backslash:

```
There are two ways to apply the filter:

- [Parallel] run\: paralellized execution, which is faster and uses more resources (recommended).
- [Sequential] run\: one image is processed at a time, which can be slow on large datasets.

#### Sequential
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I just checked again and have not bee able to reproduce the issue. Have you?